# react-native init gives ESOCKETTIMEDOUT error

Tags: react-native, npm, yarnpkg

I am using a Macbook and when I try to create a React Native app, it throws `ESOCKETTIMEDOUT` error.

I have tried to clean the npm and yarn cache however it doesn't help.

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in /Users/gaurang.shah/Documents/personal/code/mobile/AwesomeProject
Using yarn v1.13.0
Installing react-native...
yarn add v1.13.0
info No lockfile found.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/lodash/-/lodash-4.17.11.tgz: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/Users/gaurang.shah/Documents/personal/code/mobile/AwesomeProject/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

I am able to download the `https://registry.yarnpkg.com/lodash/-/lodash-4.17.11.tgz` file through my browser, so it can't be networking issue.

**Stacktrace**

```
Yarn version:
  1.13.0

Node version:
  11.10.0

Platform:
  darwin x64

Trace:
  Error: https://registry.yarnpkg.com/lodash/-/lodash-4.17.11.tgz: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT
      at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.13.0/libexec/lib/cli.js:130024:19)
      at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:285:13)
      at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:197:13)
      at TLSSocket.emitRequestTimeout (_http_client.js:669:40)
      at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:285:13)
      at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:197:13)
      at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:447:8)
      at listOnTimeout (timers.js:327:15)
      at processTimers (timers.js:271:5)

npm manifest:
  {"name":"AwesomeProject","version":"0.0.1","private":true,"scripts":{"start":"node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"}}

yarn manifest:
  No manifest

Lockfile:
  No lockfile
```

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue when retrieving big packages on a slow network. As suggested on this [comment](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/6115#issuecomment-406623932), increasing the network timeout for installing the packages worked for me.

Firstly, have your project directory created beforehand and then create a `.yarnrc` file inside of it having the following content:

```
network-timeout 600000
```

Now, just run the `react-native init <project_name>` command from the parent directory of your project as you did.

---

It is equivalent to running `yarn` like so:

```sh
yarn install --network-timeout 600000
```

Answer (score 0):

If npm can be used, please use '`npm install`' & it generates `package-lock.json` or '`yarn install --network-timeout <time in ms>`' - generates `yarn.lock`. Both works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/npx --yes --package react-native-cli react-native init hello
yes
prompt: Directory hello already exists. Continue?:  (no) (node:54861) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
yes
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in /Users/xm/WebstormProjects/hello
Using yarn v3.5.1
Installing react-native...
➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
➤ YN0032: │ fsevents@npm:2.3.2: Implicit dependencies on node-gyp are discouraged
➤ YN0061: │ uglify-es@npm:3.3.10 is deprecated: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0
➤ YN0001: │ RequestError: Socket connection timeout
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/xm/.cache/node/corepack/yarn/3.5.1/yarn.js:195:14340)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:626:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:523:35)
    at o.emit (/Users/xm/.cache/node/corepack/yarn/3.5.1/yarn.js:190:90286)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:495:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:511:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1099:20)
    at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1638:3)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 8s 421ms
➤ YN0000: Failed with errors in 8s 422ms
➤ YN0061: @npmcli/move-file@npm:2.0.1 is deprecated: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
Error: Command failed: yarn add react-native --exact
    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:885:11)
    at execSync (node:child_process:957:15)
    at run (/Users/xm/.npm/_npx/10e3bde211213596/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:294:5)
    at createProject (/Users/xm/.npm/_npx/10e3bde211213596/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:249:3)
    at /Users/xm/.npm/_npx/10e3bde211213596/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:217:7
    at /Users/xm/.npm/_npx/10e3bde211213596/node_modules/prompt/lib/prompt.js:316:32
    at /Users/xm/.npm/_npx/10e3bde211213596/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:142:25
    at assembler (/Users/xm/.npm/_npx/10e3bde211213596/node_modules/prompt/lib/prompt.js:313:9)
    at /Users/xm/.npm/_npx/10e3bde211213596/node_modules/prompt/lib/prompt.js:322:32 {
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 54864,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}
Command `yarn add react-native --exact` failed.
Done
```